# Error occurred when building NaoQI C++ SDK example project helloworld on Windows VS2010

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, nao-robot

I'm trying to install NaoQI C++ SDK on Windows following the instructions in http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/dev/cpp/install_guide.html.

I got stuck in Part E. Step.3, when running `qibuild make`. At first, it gave error messages similar to this question: https://community.aldebaran.com/en/forum/error-occurred-when-building-prodect-hellworld-1176.

After I added `add_definitions("-DNOMINMAX")` to CmakeLists.txt as suggested, the error message becomes:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'c:\NaoQi\Devtool\naoqi-sdk\lib\boost_signals-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib'
```

I cannot find any file called `boost_signals-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib` in naoqi sdk. I guess it should be compiled automatically when running `qibuild configure` or `qibuild make` but somehow it didn't.

The SDK version is `naoqi-sdk-2.0.2.53-win32-vs2010`, and OS is Windows 8.1(x64).

With Visual Studio 2010, CMake 2.8.10, qibuild 3.6.2 and Python 2.7.8.

I don't know if it makes any difference, but when running "qibuild configure", I'm getting following messages:

```
— Looking for include file pthread.h            
— Looking for include file pthread.h – not found
```

I checked `PTHREAD_INCLUDE_DIRS` which is `c:/NaoQi/Devtool/naoqi-sdk/include` and `pthread.h` is under this path.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
If anybody wants to know, here is how I solve it.

1. Compile your own boost library and copy them into naoqi-sdk/lib.
2. Open the VisualStudio solution file and change the configuration to release mode.

   The Windows version SDK doesn't have debug version ALCOMMON, ALPROXY and ALVALUE libraries. That's why the debug mode doesn't work.